# Why my Application keep calling the Class Constructor which has service Provider Parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service-provider

I'm having issues with Constructor called by default

below is my class

```cs
public class Repo : BaseRepo
{        
    public Repo :base() { }

    // Added Below Constructor for Unit Testing Purpose to pass Mock Service 
    // Provider to base Repo before it instantiates Other Services. 

    public Repo(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider) { }
}
```

When even I run my application outside of unit test project, the Constructor with service Provider Parameter is getting Called, is there a way to run this constructor only for unit test project.

I tried added symbols, but it did not work

Comment: Perhaps it will call the other one if you don't register an `IServiceProvider` provider with the DI container.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, `IServiceProvider` is always implicitly registered in the built-in ASP.NET container (a.k.a. MS.DI), as in: it won't show up in the `ServiceCollection` list, but the container will recognize it as a dependency.

Comment: Prevent letting classes in your application depend on `IServiceProvider`, because it leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). Depending on `IServiceProvider` causes a range of downsides, such as that it complicates your tests. Instead, let the class constructor accept the actually used dependencies as constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0):

By default DI is choosing constructor with maximum number of parameters it can resolve.

Try to apply attribute `[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilitiesConstructorAttribute]` to the parameterless constructor, DI should pick it up instead.